# My pictures are gone from my photo stream on my ipad

Tags: photos, streaming

My photos from Photo Stream on my iPad were here one minute, and gone next. I charged it, but it didn't show up still.

Answer (score 1):

I checked Apple support and find that the photos you upload to My Photo Stream are stored in iCloud for 30 days to give your devices plenty of time to connect and download them. If you pass the time, your photo may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Photostream only stores photos for 30 days. Could you have left them beyond that limit?

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202299